# Managing dependencies in ROS2 workspaces

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am starting a new ROS2 project and would like to use an external library that is not yet packaged for ROS ([this](https://github.com/nimbuscontrols/EIPScanner) one if that helps).

I added that source to my workspace and modified the `CMakeLists.txt` of that library to generate a `Config.cmake` file as described [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/tutorials/How-to-create-a-ProjectConfig.cmake-file). The library builds and generates the .cmake files under the workspace build directory, but it they are not discovered by a find_package statement in my CMakeLists.txt.

What is the correct ROS2/colcon/ament/cmake way to ensure an external library is built before my code? And then how do I make the necesary include and link information available in my CMakeLists.txt?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400662/managing-dependencies-in-ros2-workspaces/) by [contradict](https://answers.ros.org/users/4064/contradict/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2022-05-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-18**:
I've updated the title to better reflect your specific question @contradict.

"dependency management" is a bit broader than configuring your package to state a dependency on a specific library or other package.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-18**:
And a comment on this:

> I [..] would like to use an external library that is not yet packaged for ROS

please don't "package external libraries *for ROS*".

There is rarely a need, and it just makes maintenance harder.

Treat such libraries as all your other programs treat them: part of the OS, and discovered by something like CMake.

There isn't really anything ROS specific in how that's done.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-19**:\

> Unfortunately the edit above takes away a lot of what I wanted to know. This particular library is only an example, I am hoping to gather advice that will be useful in a more general case.

I still believe your title and question are too broad, and this has also been discussed before, but if you feel it's better to revert to the older title: I've reverted to it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've had success with this sequence:

1. In your package manifest, list `depend` tags on the library you need, i.e. `EIPScanner`.
2. In your CMakeLists.txt: `find_package(EIPScanner REQUIRED)`
3. In your CMakeLists.txt: `target_link_libraries(your_target EIPScanner)`

---

Originally posted by [aprotyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/74476/aprotyas/) with karma: 456 on 2022-05-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately the edit above takes away a lot of what I wanted to know. This particular library is only an example, I am hoping to gather advice that will be useful in a more general case.

I have a partial answer, but not a satisfactory one.

As far as I can tell, a piece of code that is already built with CMake will be built by the ros2 build system `colcon build` simply by placing it under the `src` directory of a workspace.

In order for other packages in the same workspace to depend on that library, it must generate `${PACKAGE}Config.cmake` in the directory `${prefix}/share/${PROJECT}/cmake/`. The link to the Kitware documentation in my question above gives an example of this, though it may require substantial modification of the existing `CMakeLists.txt` to get working. In order to be used as a library with the `ament_target_dependencies` macro, the `Config.camke` file needs to set at least the variables `${PROJECT}_INCLUDE_DIRS, ${PROJECT}_LIBRARY_DIRS, and ${PROJECT}_LIBRARIES`. With these conditions, `find_package` succeeds and `ament_target_dependencies` creates the necessary include and link directives.

In order to enforce a build order dependency that ensures the library is built before any package that depends on it, the project name of the library must be added as a `<depend>` tag in the appropriate `packge.xml`. Unfortunately, this breaks `rosdep install` since now that tool attempts to find a rosdep key matching the library name, which does not exist, and probably shouldn't.

For now, I have a modified version of the EIPScanner library [here](https://github.com/contradict/EIPScanner/tree/generate-cmake-config) with the changes to CMakeLists.txt needed to generate the Config file. The rosdep issue can be mitigated with the `--skip-keys` argument, though this seems difficult to maintain. The `-i` argument does not work since the library is not a catkin or ament package.

A better answer than this would 1) require fewer modifications to the existing library and 2) not break rosdep.

---

Originally posted by [contradict](https://answers.ros.org/users/4064/contradict/) with karma: 43 on 2022-05-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1